# Create table query

Tags: sql, mysql

I want to create a table for making a comment box. I was told that I should be wary of sql injection (dont even know what that means).

So I thought I should ask around at SO. my requirements are:

Comments table

1. a comment row ~400 chars
2. aid -> every comment should be linked to an aid. duplicates should be allowed. means aid = 21, can have more than 1 comment. I should be able to search through the DB to see all the comments related to aid = 21.
3. timestamp for the comment
4. userid for the comment.

A MySQL query for the above table that should not allow SQL injection. I am pretty confused. any help would be highly appreciated. thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a table usually happens only once, when the system is installed. There is, therefore, no risk of [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (which happens when a query is run with data provided by the user).

The above description would probably be implemented as:

```
CREATE TABLE `comment` ( 
  `comment_id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `comment_text` VARCHAR(400) NOT NULL,
  `aid_id` INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES `aid`(`aid_id`),
  `comment_time` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `user_id` INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES `user`(`user_id`)
);
```

Comment: it is not printing the timestamp. ie, the current time. its printing 0000-0000....also the comment_text is not updating. its null.

Comment: It is generally good practice not to use SQL reserved words as identifiers (i.e. table or column names). Although the word "comment" is not in the SQL standard ( see http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt ), it is a reserved word for DB2 ( see table 2 from http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2e/v8r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2e.doc/db2eresword.html )

Comment: A table creation query is intended to create a table, not to print anything. You might want to ask a question related to your queries for reading the data.

Answer (score 1):

Try and use [stored procedures](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-storedproc.html) in mysql .

Use parameters to pass the input to the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

thuis tutorial is for you .
http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php

Answer (score 0):

SQL injection is explained at Wikipedia and other places.

Use [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html) or [stored procedures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-programs-views.html) are standard techniques that will avoid SQL injection.